# CTreeCtrl TVN_SELCHANGED not being fired when item is clicked

Tags: mfc

I have an existing MFC application installed on many computers (000's). One user installed the current version and reports symptoms that indicate that the TVN_SELCHANGED event is not being fired when selecting items in the tree control. There is nothing odd about the computer configuration (latest Windows 7 with latest patches etc) and all else seems to work as designed.

Of importance is that the application was working fine up until a system restart a few days ago. The application is completely stand-alone (MFC statically linked), no runtime DLL's or COM components.

The Question: Can anyone shed any light as to why the TVN_SELCHANGED event might not be fired on some computer configurations (i.e A specific version of MS Office, or IE, or .NET Framework being present, not being present, common controls manifest versions etc?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you really think that TVN_SELCHANGED is not being fired try running Spy++ and see what is being reported. Are other programs which use treeviews working?

My guess is that something as basic as TVN_SELCHANGED is working just fine but that something else in the app is not working (ie the developers code) and just making it LOOK like a sel changed is not happening.